# Excel counting combinations of logical statements

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with data in multiple catagories, e.g. Pet (Dog, Cat, Rabbit), gender (M,F), mode of transport(Car,Bike,Skateboard). For each individual, these can either be true or false. I want to count the number of individuals with a particular combination of pet, gender, mode of transport. I want this to be automatic, so I can specify the gender, pet, mode of transport in cells and the formula counts based on these values.

e.g. How many people are Male, have a Dog and have a Bike? In this case, Male, Dog and Bike need to be read from cells in the spreadsheet.

I have a formula which uses indirect and offset to select columns but can't help but think there must be a better way.

Here's an example which makes it far clearer than my wordy explanation above. Thanks in advance for your help.

Is there a way of representing my data that's better suited to make this counting easier?

[Google Drive Link to Excel file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6YDH_Ayi2JyZVhUMWdGemhxOE0)

A very valid - I don't download random files from the internet comment:

Here's a csv:

```
Name,Dog,Cat,Rabbit,Male,Female,Car,Bike,Skateboard
Alice,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
Bob,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE
Chris,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
Dave,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
Ellie,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE
Frank,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
Gerald,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE
```

Also the formula I used was:

> =COUNTIFS( OFFSET(INDIRECT("R3C"&MATCH(L3,Headings,0),FALSE),0,0,numberOfPeople,1),TRUE,
>   OFFSET(INDIRECT("R3C"&MATCH(M3,Headings,0),FALSE),0,0,numberOfPeople,1),TRUE,
>   OFFSET(INDIRECT("R3C"&MATCH(N3,Headings,0),FALSE),0,0,numberOfPeople,1),TRUE)

Where numberOfPeople is a reference to a cell that counted the number of entries. And headings is a reference to the column headings of the table.

Comment: I am pretty sure this can be done with INDEX/MATCH to return the desired ranges to the countifs, but I do not down load files from the internet.  Please post the data as text in the original post.

Comment: Fair point, I've modified the question to include the data. I don't know how to use index/match to return a range of cells - how do you do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OFFSET and INDIRECT are volatile functions, in that they will recalculate every time excel calculates regardless if the underlying data has changed or not.

I prefer to use INDEX to return a range.

INDEX takes 3 criteria. INDEX(range,row,column).  By putting 0 in the row criterion it will return the full column.

so using MATCH to find the correct column and 0 for row we get the correct column returned.

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX(A:I,0,MATCH($K$2,1:1,0)),TRUE,INDEX(A:I,0,MATCH($K$3,1:1,0)),TRUE,INDEX(A:I,0,MATCH($K$4,1:1,0)),TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's much better. Is there any way to limit the column returned by index to a finite range, or are the options 1 cell or a whole row/column?

Comment: There is no detriment to referring to the full column over the smaller range but just change the first criterion in the INDEX to include the rows desired.  For example with this dataset change all the `A:I` to `A2:I8`.  This will limit the rows to the column returned.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy if you use the `COUNTIFS` formula combined with several `IF` statements. Here is what should work (put in "O3" and copy down):

```
=COUNTIFS(IF($L3=F$2,$F$3:$F$9,$G$3:$G$9),TRUE,IF($M3=C$2,$C$3:$C$9,IF($M3=D$2,$D$3:$D$9,$E$3:$E$9)),TRUE,IF($N3=H$2,$H$3:$H$9,IF($N3=I$2,$I$3:$I$9,$J$3:$J$9)),TRUE)
```

This compares the given values for your categories in the inner `IF` statements and returns the corresponding columns to check for `TRUE`. What `COUNTIFS` does then is to count all rows where the criteria is `TRUE` for all given criterias. You can also expand your categories by adding more inner `IF` statements to return corresponding rows.

It would not be quite easy to change your data representation due to the fact that you can have multiple values for one row. You would have to split data with multiple values into multiple rows. Here is an example:

[image: Example]

You could then just use the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($D$3:$D$14,$L3,$C$3:$C$14,$M3,$E$3:$E$14,$N3)
```

Having given Gender in "L3", given Pet in "M3", given Transportation in "N3".

If you have further questions, leave a comment.